# django-registration class overriding

Tags: django, overriding, django-registration

Because I need to add a captcha(django-recaptcha) to the registration form I want to override the RegistrationForm class from the django-registration module.

I am using:

- django-registration==3.3
- django==4.1
- python(3.10)

I've tried some options has shown below.

**forms.py**

```
from django_registration.forms import RegistrationForm

class MyRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    age = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta(RegistrationForm.Meta):
        fields = RegistrationForm.Meta.fields + ['age']
```

**urls.py**

```
from .forms import MyRegistrationForm
from django_registration.backends.activation.views import RegistrationView

path('accounts/register/', RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=MyRegistrationForm), name='registration_register')
```

**registration_form.html**

```
<form method="post" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Submit' %}" />
</form>
```

Nothing overrides the form. I don't understand why. Same thing for the RegistrationView. I can't override it for some reason. I've been arround these for a while now. Probably am missing something obvious by now. Help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Because in django-registration there are multiple `RegistrationView`:

- backends\activation\views.py
- backends\one_step\views.py
- views.py

Being that that the `RegistrationView` in \backends inherit from the views.py in the root. The form_class attribute is defined in the root view. So the solution I found was the one below:

#**views.py**

```
from .forms import *
from django_registration.views import RegistrationView

RegistrationView.form_class = MyRegistrationForm
```

#**forms.py**

```
from django_registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField

class MyRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    captcha = ReCaptchaField()
```

captcha is then accessible in registration_form.html through {{form}}.

**Overriding the RegistrationView**

Yet about having trouble overriding the view, the problem I was having seems to be in what order my urls were defined.

```
path('accounts/register/', MyRegistrationView.as_view(), name='registration_register'),
path('accounts/', include('django_registration.backends.activation.urls')),
```

I had to place /accounts/register before /accounts. I initially expected that by placing /accounts/register after the native urls inclusion would overwrite any others urls.